# Why does my circle look pixelated / broken?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have created one circle in illustrator but the circle quality if not perfect:

[image]

Why is the quality of the border so low?

Comment: @user19913 export the image with higher resolution, scale the image before converting

Comment: For that size, on screen, that's pretty much exactly how you can expect it to look.

Answer (score 1):

You're working with it small, so the pixels show. Scale it HUGE.

1. Select All <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Then hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag a corner of the selection out for as far as you can.
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> (that's the oh key) to alter the art board to fit your newly huge artwork.
4. Continue.

Comment: aka "make the logo bigger" :)